# c# listbox numerical order of items

Tags: c#, listbox

Hello I'm searching throught internet for hours but still I can not find the answer. (or I just don't know how to ask)

I need a simple numerical order of items in listbox fe. I am adding every 3rd items to listbox from txt file.
When I have this in txt file:

```
Acc 4
name4
pass4
Acc 5
name5
pass5
```

I'll add to listbox only `Acc4` and `Acc5`

And now when I select some item in listbox I want to know which one is selected but I don't want fe.: `Acc6` (is selected) but I want to know `Acc6`is 3nd one in listbox (then order is 2)

PS: sorry for my end and thx for help

Comment: It sounds like something is not working. Can you share the code? Or you prefer abstract monologue (if so, continue please)?

Comment: Don't you talk about myListBox.SelectedIndex; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the index of the selected item in a listbox try

```
{listBoxName}.SelectedIndex
```

This will give you the index (0 based) of a selected item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.7.2

If you want the item try

```
{listBoxName}.SelectedItem
```

This gives the currently selected item https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.7.2